# How to plot different date ranges in a single row inside google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table containing different tasks for single user that spans different date range. Please refer the Data in the attached image. I want to plot a report where I can aggregate all the date ranges for each user (refer the report in the attached image)[image]

Comment: Is it OK to use Google Apps Script or should it just use formulas?

Comment: It would be great if you can pull this just by using formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will solve your need:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(DAYS(MAX(C3:D5),MIN(C3:D5))+1,1,MIN(C3:D5)))
```

[image]

Here is the explanation:

1. `MIN`&`MAX` find the lowest and highest dates in the range `C3:D5`:
   `MAX(C3:D5),MIN(C3:D5)`
2. `DAYS` counts the number of days between `MIN`&`MAX` dates and adds `1`:
   `DAYS(MAX(C3:D5),MIN(C3:D5))+1`
3. `SEQUENCE` builds an array of all the dates from `MIN` to `MAX` including:
   `SEQUENCE(DAYS(MAX(C3:D5),MIN(C3:D5))+1,1,MIN(C3:D5))`
   and finally...
4. `TRANSPOSE` changes the display result from column to row:
   `TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(DAYS(MAX(C3:D5),MIN(C3:D5))+1,1,MIN(C3:D5)))`

Comment: thanks for the answer. But this formula does not discriminate a date where no one was assigned. For example, 13th November (E9) for john - this cell should be empty